# Unzip a file as soon as it is downloaded

Tags: bash, scripts, 22.04

Do we have any utility (or) can we write any script such that if any zip file is downloaded, it is immediately unzipped and the zip file is deleted.

Comment: You can check this link once https://www.techpond.in/automatically-unzip-file-using-inoticoming-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

##### Option 1: Download and unzip script

You can create a pretty simple script to do this. You could create the script `dlext` (short for "Download-Extract") with this content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

wget "$1"

filename="${1##*/}"

if [[ -f "./$filename" ]]
then
  case "$filename" in
    *.zip)
      echo "Zip file detected in ./$filename"
      unzip "./$filename"
      rm "./$filename"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Unknown file format in ./$filename"
      ;;
  esac
else
  echo "File not written to disk: ./$filename"
fi
```

Make the script executable, and put it in your path. In addition, unzipping files requires the package `unzip` to be installed (install with `sudo apt install unzip`).

This script is run with

```
dlext https://path.to/zipfile.zip
```

It will then fetch the file (with `wget`), check if the file was written to disk (the `if`-statement), and if true run an extraction command depending on the file extension (the `case`-statement).

I've deliberately made a `case`-statement for the file format, so you easily can add other file formats beside zip as well.

##### Option 2: Monitor downloads folder script

If you instead want to monitor a specific folder for zip files (or other files) and run a command when a new file is added to the folder, create the `dlmon` script instead:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

dlfolder="/path/to/downloads"

while inotifywait -e close_write "$dlfolder"
do
  # Create a for-loop for each file type you want to process
  for f in "$dlfolder"*.zip
  do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && unzip "$f" -d "$dlfolder" && rm "$f"
  done
done
```

This script can be run in the background, and possibly on startup using:

```
/path/to/script/dlmon &
```

Now files of the designated types that are downloaded in the downloads folder will be processed accordingly.

Comment: I see that the command `/path/to/script/dlmon &` should be executed everytime my system is up. Do we have any alternatives such that I do not need to run it everytime my system is up?

Comment: You can start it with `cron` or a similar mechanism. Please research this, search the site, and ask a new question if something is not already covered.